# What is a good way to create random word sequences to make easy-to-dictate identifiers?

Tags: identity, guid, user-experience, pgp

I am presently using GUIDs to identify certain data entities. When a customer or colleague needs to relate one of these they can, of course, copy and paste the IDs into instant messages or emails. However, they aren't very pretty and are a pain to describe over the phone or in person.

I came across the PGP cryptography suite in my youth, which includes a word list that been designed to be phonetically distinct, so you won't confuse words when heard over the phone.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGP_word_list

I wrote code that turns integer IDs into 'horse battery staple'-style identifiers using this list.

Unfortunately, the PGP word list contains many negative-sounding and distracting words. For example, I don't want a customer to ring up and say "Hey, I'm having trouble with 'drunken-Eskimo-revenge'" (in fact nearly all the random ones I tried were outrageous).

Are there any good alternatives to the PGP word list? Ideally the words should be 'phonically distinct' and inoffensive.